# Bluemix building stuck like forever

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, pipeline, building

I made some changes to the local code and tested with no problems.
Committed to repo via git succesfully.
It's staying at the building stage and precisely at the cloning stage and doesn't continue.
There is no more logs showing anything useful.
Please see attached screenshot.
Hopefully someone knows what's happening? A lot of thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try again. There was an issue with Delivery Pipeline, but everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: Thanks, it's back to normal now.